# Mongo query Limit not showing in operation

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I`m using MongoDB.Driver for .NET to query Mongo(Version 3.0.11).  This is my code to query a field  and limit the query to 200 documents.

```
BsonDocument bson = new BsonDocument();
bson.Add("Field", "Value");
BsonDocumentFilterDefinition<ResultClass> filter      = new BsonDocumentFilterDefinition<ResultClass>(bson);
FindOptions                               queryOptions    = new FindOptions() { BatchSize = 200 };
List<ResultClass> result = new List<ResultClass>();
result.AddRange(myCollection.Find<ResultClass>(filter, queryOptions).Limit(200).ToList());
```

My issue is that when I check the database`s current operations, the operation query field shows only :

> { Field : "Value" }

Which is different from the query using "AsQueryable" below:

```
List<ResultClass> result = myCollection.AsQueryable<ResultClass>().Where(t => t.Field == "Value").Take(200)
```

Query operation using "AsQueryable"

> { aggregate: "CollectionName", pipeline: [ { $match: { Field:
>   "Value" } }, { $limit: 200 } ], cursor: {} }

Why can't I see the limit in the query using Find?Is the limit being handled in the client side instead of the server?
I need to limit this in the server side but I can't use the second query because the field searched needs to be a string which can't be done using AsQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

Using limit in the first piece of code executes the limit on a cursor object, which is still serverside until you actually request the document by invoking ToList(). At which point only 200 documents will go over the wire to your application.

It looks like the AsQueryable is executing an aggregation pipeline which will show up in currentOp, but both are essentially the same.

I'm not sure if there is a performance impact for either one though